# Start Desktop Environment From Chroot

Tags: gnome, chroot, desktop-environment, systemd-nspawn

Is it possible to start a desktop environment entirely in systemd-nspawn or chroot?

I want to be able to boot to a console, then optionally enter a chroot and launch Gnome or another desktop environment.

Answer (score 4):

Launching a DM from chroot is in fact possible (if configured correctly).
A thorough tutorial can be found [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/chroot-with-second-desktop-environment-howto-and-notes-4175614913/). The process can be summarized as such:

1. Mount the special mountpoints (`/dev`, `/proc`, etc) from your host to your chroot.
2. chroot
3. Start the X server (`startx`)
4. Start your display manager

All of the corresponding commands can be synthesized into a bash script for convenience.